# Find the domain and range of $f(x) = y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$ y = \sec^{-1}(2x - x^2)$.
If you graph the equation the domain and range can be inferred
I don't how to solve it algebraically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial answer
$$
\sec:\mathbb{R}-\{\frac{k\pi}{2}\}\rightarrow(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,+\infty)
$$

$$
\sec^{-1}:(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}-\{\frac{k\pi}{2}\}
$$
where $k=\pm1,\pm3,\pm5,...$

so

$$
2x-x^{2}\leq-1\Rightarrow x\geq1+\sqrt{2},\quad x\leq1-\sqrt{2}
$$
 and

$$
2x-x^{2}\geq1\Rightarrow x=1
$$

Therefore domain will be

$$
\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R\mid}\quad x\leq1-\sqrt{2}\: or\: x=1\: or\: x\geq1+\sqrt{2}\right\} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\sec(u)=\displaystyle\frac1{\cos(u)}$, so its values satisfy $|\sec(u)|\ge 1$, and also observe that $u\ne \displaystyle\frac\pi2 +k\pi, \ (k\in\Bbb Z)$.

So, $\sec^{-1}(v)$ is defined if $|v|\ge 1$. Now applying this to $v=(2x-x^2)$, we have to solve the inequalities
$$2x-x^2\ge 1\ \ \text{ and }\ \ 2x-x^2\le -1\,.$$
For the range, the inverse function $\ v\mapsto \sec^{-1}(v)\ $ can return any values in $[0,\pi]$ except for $\pi/2$, if $v$ takes every value in $(-\infty,-1]\,\cup\,[1,\infty)$.